# Why is there a different equation to calculate the energy of a light wave?

Tags: energy, waves

Why do we calculate the energy of light with the planck equation but we don't do the same with other waves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should have the concepts clear: light is described by Maxwell's equations and carries an energy described by the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector). This is the classical framework.

In the quantum mechanical framework light is built up by innumerable photons with the Planck relation E=h*nu, but nobody counts the photons to find the energy of a light beam. The classical equations are sufficient as there is smooth continuity between the quantum frame and the classical frame.

> Why do we calculate the energy of light with the planck equation but we don't do the same with other waves?

Where necessary in order to model the physics at the quantum mechanical level, waves in media are described equivallently, as with [phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon):

> a phonon is a collective excitation in a periodic, elastic arrangement of atoms or molecules in condensed matter, like solids and some liquids. Often designated a quasiparticle

T[he energy carried by a phonon](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Winter_2013/chapter5.pdf) since it obeys quantum mechanical equation follows the Planck equation.

Actually quantum mechanics assigns *probability waves* even to particles, like electrons and atoms, and there an equation following the Planck equation , the de [Broglie equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/debrog.html#c1), holds. But this is a different story.